# Computing && and ||

Tags: scala, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I have a value in Scala defined as

```
val x = SomeClassInstance()
val someBooleanValue = x.precomputedValue || functionReturningBoolean(x)
```

`functionReturningBoolean` has a long runtime and to avoid recomputing `functionReturningBoolean(x)`, I am storing it in `x.precomputedValue`.

My question is: if `x.precomputedValue` is `true`, will `functionReturningBoolean(x)` ever be computed?

More Generally: as soon as the compiler sees a value of `true` in an "OR" statement, will it even look at the second condition in the statement?
Similarly, in an "AND" statement, such as `a && b`, will `b` ever be looked at if `a` is `false`?

Comment: Both `||` and `&&` by default exhibit short-circuiting behavior - if the first branch always evaluates to `true`, second one is never executed.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek, in case of || if the first branch evaluates to true, second one is never executed. In case of && if the first branch always evaluates to false, second one is never executed.

Comment: @ka4eli Absolutely, I forgot to specify that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is: if `x.precomputedValue` is `true`, will `functionReturningBoolean(x)` ever be computed?

No. `&&` and `||` in Scala short-circuit. You can tell from [the documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Boolean@||(x:Boolean):Boolean):

> This method uses 'short-circuit' evaluation and behaves as if it was declared as `def ||(x: => Boolean): Boolean`. If `a` evaluates to `true`, `true` is returned without evaluating `b`.

---

> More Generally: as soon as the compiler sees a value of `true` in an "OR" statement, will it even look at the second condition in the statement? Similarly, in an "AND" statement, such as `a && b`, will `b` ever be looked at if `a` is false?

Yes. All expressions in Scala must be well-typed statically, whether they will be executed at runtime or not.